# Framing Advice - Relocating Last Stud in Perpendicular Wall

Tags: framing, walkway

Thanks for any advice! We're currently in the process of creating an opening between two closets on the top floor of our house. The closest door will be removed and filled in.

I noticed there's open space between the framing for the two doors behind the last stud. It's ~1/4" wider than a 2x4. Would there be any concerns if I added a stud into the perpendicular wall to support the header so the finished wall would be flush? I'd cut the two exposed studs at my header height and leave them attached on top. Our space is very tight and removing the bump out would be great.

Nothing stands out to me but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It'd help if you sketched out what you want to do.  Thousand words, ya know.

Comment: I'm looking at your picture and your drawing and I'm having a hard time correlating the two of them. Also, I don't see where this "1/4" wider gap" is. If you could modify your drawing to include the two existing doors, or show where the removed drywall is _and_ show us where this gap is, that would help immensely.

Comment: In your "current" sketch, how do you know there's no vertical member between the two sets of blue studs?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a non bearing wall, yes you can cut the stud to the height that the top of the header will be. You may or may not find other framing in the way behind that stud after you remove it. Not knowing for sure, and since an oscillating saw will be real handy in all of this type of work, a new "pocket" can be cut into any framing that may be in the way. If there is a void or "partition blocking" that helped hold the stud in place that you removed, you can with the oscillating saw fitted with a metal cutting blade, cut the nails only holding the blocks. Set the header in place, then cut in a new jack stud that will set flush with the surface of the wall framing to hold the end of the new header.

If it is  bearing wall, this area will need a new king stud in place first before adding the header. Then the jack stud goes in. It would be better to open the outside wall in the hall or other room to allow better nailing if this is a bearing wall.